# tccutil reset All breaks permissions

Tags: macos, permission

I was following some article the other day, where `tccutil reset All` was proposed as a troubleshooting method. After I did this, no app would ask me again for Camera and Microphone permission, despite the obvious lack of it. It just never showed up on the menu, and Apple doesn't let us add apps manually to these lists.

I have managed to get my permissions working by turning SIP back on, as well as choosing the "best security" option in the Recovery. After a reboot, everything works as intended. However, I want to have my SIP disabled all the time, without having to disable it to grant a basic permissions.

Have anyone experienced that?

*MacOS Ventura 13.1

Comment: So, is everything working as it should now, or not? There are very few good reasons for disabling SIP, and SIP is only one of many security features. What was the problem you were 'troubleshooting'? It sounds like your attempts to customise the security have done more damage than good. What model of Mac is this? Perhaps update to 13.2 might help?

Comment: I am on MBA M1, I have SIP disabled for a long time now. Initially to hide orange dot in the top right corner of the screen. Later it came in handy when I sideloaded some iOS apps too. As I said, I would prefer to keep SIP disabled while also being able to grant permissions, which I now can not.

Comment: Nothing will ever ask for camera/mic perms etc with SIP off. That's just one of those things. Switching off SIP has become less & less useful with each OS iteration. The 'glitch/intentional irritation' for camera/mic perms has been there since Mojave.

Comment: That just doesn't make any sense to me! Thanks for the information, I would never have figured they would do such a thing.

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out. It is, however & whatever the underlying thinking, annoyingly true.

Comment: If you still have this problem (hope not given how long its been), I had a similar issue.  Check the answer at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460428/macos-ventura-apps-do-not-ask-for-permissions-after-tccutil-reset